# apiParam(Example) and Objects

Tags: api-doc

I don't know why this won't work. The doc says:

```
/**
 * @api {get} /user/:id
 * @apiSuccess {Boolean} active        Specify if the account is active.
 * @apiSuccess {Object}  profile       User profile information.
 * @apiSuccess {Number}  profile.age   Users age.
 * @apiSuccess {String}  profile.image Avatar-Image.
 */
```

And this is my code

```
 * @apiParam {Object}    file
 * @apiParam {String}    file.bucket
 * @apiParam {String}    file.key
 * @apiParam {String}    file.name
 *
 * @apiParamExample {json} Request:
 * {
 *          "file": {
 *              "bucket": "testmediabucket1",
 *              "key": "key2",
 *              "name": "klassefoto.jpg"
 *          }
 * }
 *
 * @apiSuccessExample
 *      true
```

The PowerShell gives me following errors: *Mismatch in @apiParamExample and @apiParam! The parameter 'file.bucket' does not exist*, as well as *'file.key'* and *'file.name'*.

Answer (score 0):

may be work like this

- @apiParam {Object}    file
- @apiParam {String}    file[bucket]
- @apiParam {String}    file[key]
- @apiParam {String}    file[name]